# MySQL: where max date in joined table less than

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables - `client`, `invoice` and `invoice_item`. I need to select all clients, that have last date purchase less than specific date. Date purchase stored in `invoice_item` table, items assigned to an invoice, and invoice assigned to a client. Here is what I tried

```
SELECT c.* FROM client c
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT i.client_id as clid, MAX(item.date_created) as mdt
            FROM invoice i
            INNER JOIN invoice_item item on i.id = item.invoice_id
            GROUP BY i.id
            ) joined
ON joined.clid = c.id
WHERE joined.mdt  < date('2017-01-01')
```

And also

```
SELECT c.* FROM client c
WHERE c.id IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT i.client_id FROM invoice i
            INNER JOIN invoice_item item on i.id = item.invoice_id
            GROUP BY i.id
            HAVING MAX(item.date_created) < date('2017-01-01')
            )
```

Both queries return wrong result, here is a query I'm using to check correctness:

```
SELECT MAX(invoice_item.date_created) FROM invoice_item
INNER JOIN invoice i on invoice_item.invoice_id = i.id 
WHERE client_id = {some id from the previous query};
```

The query above returns date, greater than `2017-01-01` for some clients.

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You group data by an identifier of an invoice in subquery, but you should group data by client_id in your subquery.

```
SELECT c.* FROM client c
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT i.client_id as clid, MAX(item.date_created) as mdt
            FROM invoice i
            INNER JOIN invoice_item item on i.id = item.invoice_id
            GROUP BY i.client_id
            ) joined
ON joined.clid = c.id
WHERE joined.mdt  < date('2017-01-01')
```